# How to implement Scala apply method in Java

Tags: java, scala

I want to call some Java code from Scala code. I would like to use Scala's apply construct, so I can call it like this:

```
val led = OutPin(0)
```

instead of:

```
val led = new OutPin(0)
```

I naively implemented an additional *apply* method in my Java code like this:

```
public class OutPin {

    public OutPin(int pinNumber) {
    }

    public OutPin apply(int pinNumber) {
        return new OutPin(pinNumber);
    }
}
```

This does not make my Scala code (first line above) compile, and instead gives me an error:

*Object OutPin is not a value*

What is the correct way to implement Scala's apply method in Java?

Comment: Try to make `apply` static: `public static OutPin apply(int pinNumber)`

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just implement the apply function in Scala? I guess as a minimum, you would need to make apply static and make a static import of the apply function.

Comment: In fact I did try it as a static method before, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: The apply method must be defined in the companion object of the class. The class of the companion object is not the same as your defined class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is not with the apply method per-se, but with trying to implement a Scala singleton object in Java.

I think (but am not certain) that this is very difficult, perhaps even impossible, by design.

Consider a very, very simple case:

```
object Obj;
```

This compiles to two JVM bytcode files, `Obj$.class` and `Obj.class`. In theory, it should be easy to just inspect the bytecode of those two classes, and reexpress the same thing in Java. The basic structure of Scala singleton objects is very, very simple:

1. For a singleton object `Obj`, a `Obj.class` and `Obj$.class` must be generated
2. The `Obj$` class must have a `public final static` field of type `Obj$` called `MODULE$`, which will be initialized on class initialization refer to the singleton object. In Scala, calls to `Obj.foo()` get mapped to `Obj$.MODULE$.foo()` [...if Obj had a method called `foo()`, that is!]
3. The Java compiler doesn't know anything about these Scala generated class pairs, so for Java interop, the `Obj` class contains static functions that just forward to a call of a method of the same name and signature on `Obj$.MODULE$`.

That sounds complicated, but it's really not so much. It's trivial to write a pair of Java classes that goes this far. But the Scala compiler (2.10.3) still won't recognize the pair as constituting a Scala singleton. Diving into the bytecode of a Scala-compiler generated singleton, you'll see that there are details that are hard to express in legal Java. [Hint: `javap -c -p -s -v <fully-qualified-class-name>`]

For example, the final static `MODULE$` field is initialized indirectly by the static initializer. The static initializer just constructs an `Obj$` object, without directly assigning it. The assignment occurs within the private constructor. That's illegal in Java: blank static finals must be certainly initialized in the static initializer, and cannot be assigned in code (like the private constructor) that might potentially be called from outside the initializer and multiple times. The Scala compiler generates bytecode that respects the blank final semantics (because the private constructor is only called once), but exceeds the Java compiler's ability to verify those semantics. So this code would be rejected if expressed in Java.

Also, the `Obj` class (the version without the terminal dollar sign) includes an annotation of type [ScalaSig](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.2/scalap/index.html#scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSig), which looks quite complicated and would be hard to reproduce by hand (in Java or in Scala), at least for those of us unsure exactly how this annotation works.

I don't know exactly what the Scala compiler looks for before deciding to treat a pair of classes as a "value", that is a valid Scala singleton object, but Scala's designers have chosen not to make it easy, despite the simplicity of the basic scheme. Probably they wish to preserve the ability to reorganize how scala singleton objects translate to bytecode. Letting Java programmers synthesize scala singleton objects would effectively render the current scheme a permanent part of Scala's public API.

Note that writing an ordinary, non-singleton class whose instances have an apply(...) method and so can be called like functions is easy from Java and works fine. Here's a Java cat:

```
public class Cat {
    public String apply( int i ) {
        return "Meow: " + i;
    }
}
```

Here's a use of Scala's sugared apply:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val Morris = new Cat;
Morris: Cat = Cat@6b4feafa

scala> Morris(8)
res0: String = Meow: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an apply method that is usable in Scala you should implement it on the scala an  side using `object` to wrap your java class with the same name of the class which instantiate it

```
object OutPin {

   def apply(pinNumber :Int) = new OutPin(pinNumber)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Scala compiler says you must define two companion objects in the same file, otherwise you get the error:

```
Companions 'class OutPin' and 'object OutPin' must be defined in same file
```

Here is another approach that might work for you.  If you define your Scala `OutPin` in a separate package, then it will work.  For example:

Java class:

```
package base;

public class OutPin {
    private final int i;

    public OutPin(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
}
```

Scala class:

```
package base.scala

object OutPin {
  def apply(i: Int): base.OutPin = new base.OutPin(i)
}
```

Sample Scala client:

```
import base.scala.OutPin

object Client extends App {
  val op = OutPin(1)

  println(op.getI)
}
```

Running Client prints `1`

To get access to the sugared `apply` you would have to import `base.scala` instead of just `base`.   If it's really important to get the apply syntax it might be worth it.